# Stripping encapsulating characters in PHP using sscanf

Tags: php, string, scanf

Using PHP to call a Java app, the Java app returns a string encapsulated by "[....]", I need to remove the outside brackets and maintain what's inside -a mix of integers, strings, and other special chars like (, etc.. I'm using sscanf successfully later in the process, so I'm a little lost as to why this particular step is so difficult.

Input:

```
 $str = [(123)[334.5 : 765.1] string]
```

Non-functional code:

```
$format = '[%s]';
sscanf($str,$format,$output);
```

Later in the process I'm successfully using sscanf to parse the inside string using:

```
$format = '(%d) [%f : %f] %s';
```

I'm missing something big here...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the string is *always* wrapped in [...] and you don't need to check for incorrectly formatted strings, you can simply remove the first and last characters:

```
$str = substr($str, 1, -1);
```

*Edit*: This is more reliable than using trim() and friends because ltrim/rtrim will remove all leading/trailing square brackets, not just the first and last one. This could be a problem if your string ever contains something like "[[value]..]" - you'd be left with "value]..".

*Another edit*: If you *do* need to check if the string is formatted correctly, it's easy to verify that the first and last characters are square brackets:

```
if ((substr($str, 0, 1) == '[') && (substr($str, -1) == ']')) {
    $str = substr($str, 1, -1);
} else {
    //Something went wrong - the string is not wrapped in [brackets].
}
```

Comment: +1 and OP is failing probably because there are multiple [ ] in the input or possibly REGEX character

Comment: +1 My method *will* remove double square brackets, but at the same time, this method will remove the first char if the bracket *isn't* there.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I tried both methods, each worked well but I'm going with this one for 'clarity'.

Comment: Fluffeh: Good point. Luckily, it's trivial to check for that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)() and [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)() functions to get rid of the external brackets:

```
$str = '[(123)[334.5 : 765.1] string]';
$str = ltrim($str, "[");
$str = rtrim($str, "]");
echo $str;
```

Answer (score -1):

Source: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#:~:text=s%20stops%20reading%20at%20any%20whitespace%20character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#:%7E:text=s%20stops%20reading%20at%20any%20whitespace%20character).

> **format**
> The interpreted format for string, which is described in the documentation for sprintf() with following differences:
>
> [...]
>
> - s stops reading at any whitespace character.

Your format string is failing because there are whitespace characters between the braces.

Assuming your `string` substring at the end of your input string contains no closing braces, you can instead use a negated character class containing a closing brace.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MpdHV))

```
$str = '[(123)[334.5 : 765.1] string]';

var_export(
    sscanf($str, '[(%d)[%f : %f] %[^]]]')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 123,
  1 => 334.5,
  2 => 765.1,
  3 => 'string',
)
```